# define Get and put

Tags: haskell, monads

For a school programming exercise i'm asked to implement `get` and `put` in terms of `modify` and `modify` in terms of `get` and `put`. So I've been puzzling with a few stack overflow posts and other material to put the pieces together. this is what i have thus far

```
class Monad m => MonadState m s | m -> s where

    get :: m s
    get  =  modify id -- (\s -> s)

    put :: s -> m ()
    put s = do
        modify (\_ -> s)
        return ()


    modify :: (s -> s) -> m s
    modify f = do
        x <- get
        let newX = f x
        put x
        return newX
```

I already figured that its not functioning properly, so my question is how do i test this code in ghci? and maybe push me in the right direction.

Edit: 
The whole monad idea is a bit overwhelming and I honestly have no idea how I could test it or see it at work.

Comment: The only problem I see is that `put x` should be `put newX`.

Comment: To test that code you need to define an instance. Define a standard `State` monad (or any other monad having some state inside), first providing only `get,put` and test the derived `modify`. Then, define only `modify` in the instance, and test the derived `get,put`.

Comment: and maybe it is just here at stackoverflow but I think your `modify` has incorrect indentation after the `do`.

Comment: `modify :: m ()`, `\_ -> s == const s`

Comment: Theoretically `modify f = get >>= (\x -> put $ f x) >> get`, or `modify f = do x <- get; put $ f x; get`